# how google handle multi website login in the same time

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

I follow this scenario:
1.open gmail
2.login to gmail
3.logged in successfully
4.open Youtube
5.i see i am logged in 
I wonder how google handle this to login to multiple domain in the same time

Answer (score 0):

Google uses Outh for this.

Basically they have made a key value pair in which they store a token agains your emailid somewhere, if you have logged in even once in any google suite's website then they will store this token.

Every time you login to any website, then they will check wether you have that token in place, if you have it then you are logged in earlier, otherwise you have to login again.

see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxRXLbgX53A for reference.